# PHP : User update method inside insert Method

Tags: php

I have a little problem when I try to validating the condition in my insert method.

This is what I want :

- if data not exist, do insert data
- if data exist in 'isActive' is `'true'`, send error `'data already exist'`
- if data exist in 'isActive' is `'false'`, run `update method`

But it seems my method can not run smoothly.

this is my `insert method` :

```
        public function InsertUserCard(UserCard $uc)
        {
            //get kartu
            $user_card = $this->GetUserCardByCardIdByUserId($uc);

            if(!$user_card)
            {
                $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$this->table_name."
                                             (user_card_id, user_id, card_id, card_number, barcode, barcode_format, created_at, updated_at) 
                                             VALUES('', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                if ($stmt == FALSE)
                {
                    die($this->conn->error);
                }
                else  
                {
                    $user_id = NULL;
                    $card_id = NULL;
                    $card_number = NULL;
                    $barcode = NULL;
                    $barcode_format = NULL;
                    $created_at = NULL;
                    $updated_at = NULL;
                    $stmt->bind_param("iisssss", $user_id, $card_id, $card_number, $barcode, $barcode_format, $created_at, $updated_at);
                    $user_id = $uc->getUserId();
                    $card_id =  $uc->getCardId();
                    $card_number = $uc->getCardNumber();
                    $barcode = $uc->getBarcode();
                    $barcode_format = $uc->getBarcodeFormat();
                    $created_at = $uc->getCreatedAt();
                    $updated_at = $uc->getUpdatedAt();
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $result = $this->conn->insert_id; 
                    $stmt->close();
                }

                // Check for successful insertion
                if ($result) 
                {
                    // User card successfully inserted
                    return $result;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    // Failed to insert user card
                    return USER_CARD_INSERT_FAILED;
                }
            }
            else if($user_card->getisActive() == 'true')
            {
                return USER_CARD_ALREADY_EXISTED;
            }
            else {
                // this is where I try to run the update method
                $uc->setUserCardId($user_card->getUserCardId());

                $this->UpdateUserCard($uc);
                return $uc->getUserCardId();
            }
        }
```

in last condition, I try to run the update method if the data is exists but 'isActive' value is `'false'`

This is my update method :

```
        public function UpdateUserCard(UserCard $uc) 
        {

                $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE ".$this->table_name."
                                              SET user_id = ?,
                                              card_id = ?,
                                              card_number = ?,
                                              barcode = ?,
                                              barcode_format = ?,
                                              isActive = ?,
                                              updated_at = ?                                  
                                              WHERE user_card_id = ? 
                                              AND user_id = ?");
                if($stmt == FALSE)
                {
                    die($this->conn->error);
                }
                else 
                {
                    $user_id = NULL;
                    $card_id = NULL;
                    $card_number = NULL;
                    $barcode = NULL;
                    $format = NULL;
                    $isActive = NULL;
                    $updated_at = NULL;
                    $user_card_id = NULL;

                    $stmt->bind_param("iisssssii", $user_id,
                                                $card_id,
                                                $card_number, 
                                                $barcode, 
                                                $format,
                                                $isActive,
                                                $updated_at,
                                                $user_card_id, 
                                                $user_id);
                    $user_id = $uc->getUserId();
                    $card_id = $uc->getCardId();
                    $card_number = $uc->getCardNumber();
                    $barcode = $uc->getBarcode();
                    $format = $uc->getBarcodeFormat();
                    $isActive = $uc->getisActive();
                    $updated_at = $uc->getUpdatedAt();
                    $user_card_id = $uc->getUserCardId();

                    $stmt->execute();
                    $num_affected_rows = $stmt->affected_rows;
                    $stmt->close();
                    return $num_affected_rows > 0;
                }

                // Check for successful insertion
                if ($stmt->execute()) 
                {
                    // User card successfully inserted
                    return USER_CARD_INSERTED_SUCCESSFULLY;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    // Failed to insert user card
                    return USER_CARD_INSERT_FAILED;
                }

        }
```

and the last is my GetUserCardByCardIdByUserId Method :

```
        private function GetUserCardByCardIdByUserId(UserCard $card) 
        {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_card_id, user_id, card_id, card_number, barcode, barcode_format, isActive, created_at, updated_at 
                                          FROM ". $this->table_name ."
                                          WHERE card_id = ? AND user_id = ?");
            if ($stmt == FALSE)
            {
                die($this->conn->error);
            } 
            else  
            {
                $card_id = NULL;
                $user_id = NULL;
                $stmt->bind_param("ii", $card_id, $user_id); 
                $card_id = $card->getCardId();
                $user_id = $card->getUserId();
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->bind_result($user_card_id,
                                   $user_id, 
                                   $card_id,
                                   $card_number,
                                   $barcode,
                                   $barcode_format,
                                   $isActive,
                                   $created_at,
                                   $updated_at);
                $stmt->store_result();
                $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;

                if($num_rows != 1)
                    return NULL;
                else {
                    $card = new UserCard();
                    $card->setUserCardId($user_card_id);
                    $card->setUserId($user_id);
                    $card->setCardId($card_id);
                    $card->setBarcode($barcode);
                    $card->setBarcodeFormat($barcode_format);
                    $card->setisActive($isActive);
                    $card->setCreatedAt($created_at);
                    $card->setUpdatedAt($updated_at);

                    $stmt->close();
                    return $card;
                }
            }
        }
```

please check my method if I write wrong structure of code.

thanks :)

Comment: what are errors you are getting when run this code

Comment: I got no error, but when I set the data on 'isActive == false, the method not run the update method

Comment: echo isActive ; check what value is present in every method .